# Find x inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Find $x$($x$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$) from this inequality:

$$-\frac1{28}\leq\frac1{3^n+1}\leq\frac1{28} $$

I tried something,but I think it's wrong..

$$-3^n-1\leq28\leq3^n+1$$

$$-3^n\leq29\leq3^n+2$$

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, and the answer should be $n \ge 3$

Comment: Where is $x$? Are you trying to find $n$?

Answer (score 3):

Not that the middle term is never negative(it's always positive), so the inequality can be transformed to:

$$-\frac{1}{28} < 0 < \frac{1}{3^n+1} \le \frac{1}{28}$$

Then, following normal steps we can see:

$$3^n +1 \ge 28 \Rightarrow n \ge 3$$

Answer (score 0):

It think that this is correct. It will then lead you to conclude that $n \geq 3 $